# Promise.all not working correctly with array of Mongo Queries

Tags: javascript

I have an array (**recommendedRoutes**) of routes that I need to iterate over and get the owner (**User**) of the route from MongoDB. I then attach an additional **userObj** to the route after I get it from the database.

```
let promiseArr = [];

for (let index = 0; index < obj.recommendedRoutes.length; index++) {
    console.log("Pushed: "+index);
    promiseArr.push( 
        User.find({
            _id : obj.recommendedRoutes[index].userId,
        },(err,data) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Database error: " + err);
            }else{
                obj.recommendedRoutes[index].userObj = data[0].toObject();
                console.log("Completed: "+index);
            }
        })
    );    
}
```

I need to return this array after I have attached the **userObj** to all the route objects in the array. So I pushed all the queries into a **promiseArr** and used Promise.all to ensure I only return the array when all the promises have been resolved.

```
Promise.all(promiseArr)
.then(() => {

    console.log("Return Object");
    return res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
        message: "Successfully retrieved Recommended Routes/Carpools",
        obj: obj,
    });

})
.catch((e) => {
    throw "There was an error: "+e;
});
```

The problem is that it occasionally returns the array before the promises resolves.
Expected output:

```
Pushed: 0
Pushed: 1
Completed: 1
Completed: 0
Return Object
```

What happens occasionally:

```
Pushed: 0
Pushed: 1
Completed: 1
Return Object
Completed: 0
```

Comment: If you pass a callback to mongo `find`, it doesn't return a promise. Use `then` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using Promises but callbacks...

This is the correct way:

```
for (let index = 0; index < obj.recommendedRoutes.length; index++) {
  console.log('Pushed: ' + index);
  promiseArr.push(
    User.find({
      _id: obj.recommendedRoutes[index].userId,
    }).then((data) => {
      obj.recommendedRoutes[index].userObj = data[0].toObject();
      console.log('Completed: ' + index)
    }, err => console.log('Database error: ' + err))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the name of better code, please await all responses before you start updating your `recommendedRoutes`.

With you current approach, you update the individual route-objects as soon as the respective response arrives. Between these responses your array is in a transitional state. It doesn't contain the (entirety of) old data anymore, but not yet the (entire) new data from the server; and god forbid that anyone of your requests may fail. How do you roll back OR move forward from this, as each update (every item in the array) is handled individually.

@m1ch4ls answer also has the same problem, it just fixes your use of callbacks instead of the promises.

imho. some better code

```
Promise.all(
    //make all the individual requests
    obj.recommendedRoutes.map(
        route => User.find({ _id: route.userId })
    )
).then(
    //and only whe they ALL have returned successfully 
    data => {
        //update all your state at once
        data.forEach((item, index) => {
            obj.recommendedRoutes[index].userObj = item.toObject()
        });
    },
    err => {
        //or return an error-message if anyone fails
        console.log("Database error: " + err);
    }
);
```